# React useContext not updating automatically

Tags: reactjs

Am experiencing an issue trying to update my components. For Instance when I update the cart, it does not reflect automatically. Below is my AppProvider. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

const AppContext = createContext(null);

const AppProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [favourites, setFavourites] = useState([]);


  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        setUser,
        cart,
        setCart,
        favourites,
        setFavourites,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

export { AppContext, AppProvider };
```

Comment: The context provider looks good to me. Something must have gone wrong with the context consumer or its updater. You need to provide more for other to help you.